# Jquery ui: How to toggle backup when mouse out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-hover

I have the following code. When I mouse over/hover over the drop down box it opens up.

How do I make the drop down box toggle back up for the mouseout?

**CSS** in the `<head>`

```
body { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; font-size:0.75em; color:#000;}
        .desc { color:#6b6b6b;}
        .desc a {color:#0092dd;}
        .dropdown dd, .dropdown dt, .dropdown ul { margin:0px; padding:0px; }
        .dropdown dd { position:relative; }
        .dropdown a {color:0092DD !important;text-decoration:none; outline:none;}
        .dropdown a:visited { color:#0092DD; text-decoration:none; outline:none;}
        .dropdown a:hover { color:#0092DD;}
        .dropdown dt a:hover, .dropdown dt a:focus
            { color:#0092DD !important; border: 1px solid #0092DD;}
        .dropdown dt a {background:#fff url(./img/arrow.png) no-repeat scroll right center; display:block; padding-right:20px;
 border:1px solid #0092DD; width:47px; border-radius:6px;
-moz-border-radius:6px }
        .dropdown dt a span {cursor:pointer; display:block; padding:5px;}
        .dropdown dd ul { background:#ccc none repeat scroll 0 0; border:1px solid #000; color:#0092DD; display:none;
left:0px; padding:5px 0px; position:absolute; top:2px; width:auto; min-width:117px; list-style:none;}
        .dropdown span.value { display:none;}
        .dropdown dd ul li a { padding:5px; display:block; color:#000 !important;}
        .dropdown dd ul li a:hover { background-color:#777; color:#fff !important}
        .dropdown img.flag { border:none; vertical-align:middle; margin-left:10px; }
        .flagvisibility { display:none;}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

<head>

    <title>drop down with CSS and jQuery - demo</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <dl id="sample" class="dropdown">
        <dt><a href="#"><span>Actions</span></a></dt>
        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">UK<img class="flag" src="br.png" alt="" /><span class="value">UK</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">France<img class="flag" src="fr.png" alt="" /><span class="value">FR</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <span id="result"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript** also in the `<head>`

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $(".dropdown img.flag").addClass("flagvisibility");
           $(".dropdown dt a").hover(function() {
                $(".dropdown dd ul").toggle();
            });


             $(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() {
                var text = $(this).html();
                $(".dropdown dt a span").html(text);
                $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
                $("#result").html("Selected value is: " + getSelectedValue("sample"));
                alert(getSelectedValue("sample"));
            });
            function getSelectedValue(id) {
                return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
            }

            $(document).bind('hover', function(e) {
                var $clicked = $(e.target);
                if (! $clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown"))
                    $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
            });

            $("#flagSwitcher").hover(function() {
                $(".dropdown img.flag").toggleClass("flagvisibility");
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: What's the actual behavior? I can see it's toggling when hovering in and out

Comment: when i mouse over the dropdown opens, but  if i do not select anything from the dropdown ir doesnot close.

Comment: I created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5dpG3/ but the earliest version of jQuery they have hotlinked is 1.6.4. Is there a particular reason you're using 1.3.2? Can you verify this example has the problem you're experiencing? I'm having trouble clicking on anything because of the gap between the `action` span and the drop down bit.

Comment: I will be using the latest jquery 1.8.2 or or later. sorry i forgot to update the jquery version from 1.3.2

Comment: I will be using the latest jquery 1.8.3 or or later. sorry i forgot to update the jquery version from 1.3.2. I am noticing that too. once i update to 1.8.3 i am no longer able to click on the items. I was using the code from  "JankoAtWarpSpeed demos"

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle?